# Translate default errors in Flask-WTF

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, python-babel

I am trying to translate the default messages from WTForms using the Flask-WTF plugin.
According to this(https://github.com/ajford/flask-wtf/pull/65) it should be working. You can also see that wtforms use gettext for their default error messages(https://bitbucket.org/simplecodes/wtforms/src/113994790508/wtforms/validators.py).

I added WTF_I18n_ENABLED to my config file and I created my .po file using the following commands

```
pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -k lazy_gettext -o messages.pot myapp
pybabel init -i messages.pot -d myapp/translations -l en
pybabel compile -d myapp/translations
```

I expected the default messages to appear there but they don't. Am I expecting too much or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Flask can search translations only on one folder (`translations` by default and not on eggs). So you need copypaste `wtforms.mo`/`wtforms.po` files to your application `LS_MESSAGES`.

Comment: Helpful but I still can't make it work. I have compiled to both messages.mo and wtforms.mo and it doesn't work.

Comment: I use next command `PATH_TO_PYTHON_ENV/bin/pybabel compile -f -d PATH_TO_FLASK_PROJECT/translations/` and it fork fine for me. What `babel` and `flask babel` versions and what WTForm classes you use?

Comment: I am using virtualenv, so I have the latest versions provided by pip.

Comment: copy the content of wtforms.po into your messages.po, then translate them